# Como pegar o penúltimo e antipenultímo item de um array

Tags: php

Tenho um *array* que vem de um retorno de um `form` e gostaria de saber de como pegar a penúltima e a antepenúltima posição do mesmo em PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basicamente se utiliza o `count()` para obter o número de itens que possui na array, embora haja outras opções.

Havendo por exemplo:

```
$array = ['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis'];
```

Pode obter o **último** utilizando:

```
$array[ count($array) - 1  ];
```

Logo, para obter o penúltimo e o antepenúltimo é apenas matematica, ao invés de `-1` utilize `- 2` e `- 3`, por exemplo:

```
$penultimo = $array[ count($array) - 2  ];
$antepenultimo = $array[ count($array) - 3  ];
```

[**Teste isto aqui.**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f78efc5624acbc3a2cc152d3705cee7c82487e3e)

---

Uma outra opção é utilizando o `end()` e depois o `prev()`, num exemplo:

```
$array = ['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis'];    

$ultimo = end($array);
$penultimo = prev($array);
$antepenultimo = prev($array);

reset($array);
```

**[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b63f99ae66b1463ccd2351f7af2bccc505ac33c)**

O `end` moverá para o último item, depois o `prev()` irá obter o anterior.

---

Uma outra forma de obter é utilizando o `array_slice`, por exemplo:

```
$array = ['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis'];  

list($antePenultimo, $penultimo, $ultimo) = array_slice($array, -3);
```

**[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b06188fe08558610fd6be88d43b2d3cc23d63e81)**

Neste caso é um pouco diferente, o `array_slice` irá criar uma nova array, porém esta irá conter apenas os três últimos valores, devido ao `-3`.

Se você deseja apenas o antepenúltimo e o penúltimo poderá definir um `length`, que é o terceiro parâmetro, assim definindo para `2` irá obter antepenúltimo, por exemplo:

```
list($antePenultimo, $penultimo) = array_slice($array, -3, 2);
```

Se você quiser inverter a ordem utilize o `array_reverse()` e se quiser preservar as chaves adicione o `true` no quarto parâmetro, por exemplo:

```
foreach(array_reverse(array_slice($array, -3, 2)) as $texto){
    echo $texto;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a37c39bf53db88a00690ce401252790ab2fe76e7)**

Comment: Boa, resposta bem completa, valeu

Answer (score 4):

Mais algumas alternativas:

```
$array = ['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis'];

$ultimoAntepenultimo = array_splice( $array, -3, 2 );
```

(use o `slice` no lugar de `splice` se não quiser retirar do original)

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/DuCUX3)**.

Se quiser separado, e não tiver problema de remover da original, pode usar isto:

```
$array = ['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis'];

$ultimo = array_pop( $array );
$penultimo = array_pop( $array );
$antePenultimo = array_pop( $array );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/JdKrrB)**.

A vantagem neste caso é não criar novo *array*.

Answer (score 4):

Outra forma de fazer isso é combinar as funções `end()` que coloca o ponteiro do array na última posição e chamar `prev()` que coloca ele na posição anterior então isso dá a penúltima posição. Usei `reset()` no exemplo para colocar o ponteiro do array no início.

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9);
end($arr);
$penultimo = prev($arr);
$antepenultimo = prev($arr);

echo 'Penultimo: '. $penultimo .' | Antepenultimo: '.$antepenultimo;
```

Comment: Muito boa alternativa.

Answer (score 2):

```
Array[0] // primeiro item
Array[Array.length - 1] // Ultimo item

//No caso do PHP acho que é mais ou menos isso
$Array[0]
$Array[count($Array) - 1]
```

Eu uso dessa forma.

Comment: valeu, vou testar